# Typescript-related error in a legacy project

Tags: .net, visual-studio, typescript, npm

I'm working on a legacy code base. I received the code via .zip file, which obviously contained everything the previous developer needed. I put the solution under source control, using a boilerplate `.gitignore`. I'm trying to develop on my home home machine, and running into an error that I've never encountered before while trying to build the app. Clearly, a file that I never knew I needed was ignored. Furthermore, this is related to typescript. Beyond my knowledge of its existence, I know `null` about the language.

These are the errors I encounter while trying to build the app:

`Build:File 'C:/path/to/solution/node_modules/specificity/specificity.d.ts' not found.`

`Build:File 'C:/path/to/solution/node_modules/isobject/index.d.ts' not found.`

What I'm guessing is happening is Typescript was included in this app at some point, and then not completely removed. Some configuration is initiating compilation that can't complete due to files being ignored when I committed from my work computer.

I'm hoping these two files are standard files recognizable by someone who knows typescript. I'd like to remove the traces of typescript from this project, as it's all `.NET 4.5` and `ExtJS` at this point.

I realize it's a big ask, since I'm not entirely sure what's going on here.

**EDIT**

Reading more, it looks like this is an issue related to a node module, and that module's typescript support. I'll likely remove this question and ask a more specific question about `Visual Studio` and app building, but I'd still appreciate any input.

Answer (score 1):

`*.d.ts` file is the type definition file (aka typings file).

There is no reason to exclude them. Your IDE/compiler just uses that information to help you during your development.

The problem you face is due to in `specificity/package.json` and `isobject/package.json`, it contains `typings` or `types` field, which tells your IDE/compiler that these packages distributes their own typings files.

Since you exclude them, the IDE/compiler complains.